# Different national and international shipping rate in Satchmo?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I'm taking over a Satchmo site and need it to charge a different shipping rate for international versus local postage.

Any idea what I need to do to enable this?

Comment: OK, it seems like the tieredweight shipping module is what I need here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the tieredweight shipping module is what I need here.